# How to install Electrum 2.6.4 bitcoin wallet on Mint 18

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, bitcoin

Today's question of mine was **How do I install Electrum 2.6.4** Bitcoin wallet on my Linux Mint 18.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
sudo apt-get install python-qt4 python-pip
sudo pip install https://download.electrum.org/2.6.4/Electrum-2.6.4.tar.gz#md5=4840a883e60083d055064d5614c3353e
```

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of Electrum are available for download. At the time of writing this, there were similar instructions to what @Vlastimil posted, but slightly altered for version 3.0, [available here on the electrum.org website](https://electrum.org/#download).

> Install dependencies:
>
> `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5 python3-pip`
>
> Install Electrum:
>
> `sudo pip3 install https://download.electrum.org/3.0/Electrum-3.0.tar.gz`